Kql function to append columns
I have a kusto table. I want to append column(s) to each row based on custom logic using one of the columns in the table. I tried Invoke command. It didn't work.
.create-or-alter function Test(input: string, column: dynamic) {
    // custom logic
    tostring(column.value1);
}

I want to achieve something like below. Pass the column for each row and append the result
 MyTable | Invoke Test("inputString", column)

Does kql supports this ?

if I understand your intention correctly, you could try something like this:
let T = datatable(a:string, b:dynamic)
[
    "hello", dynamic({"A":1,"B":2,"value1":3}),
    "world", dynamic({"value1":4,"value2":5}),
]
;
let F = (T:(b:dynamic)) {
    T | extend b.value1
}
;
T | invoke F()




a
b
b_value1




hello
{  "A": 1,  "B": 2,  "value1": 3}
3


world
{  "value1": 4,  "value2": 5}
4




Great. I was trying something similar earlier as well. But your example put me through correct path. Thanks
